# Proguard retrace isnt mapping the stack trace to the actual source

Tags: android, proguard

I have been using the eclipse built in proguard tool to obsucate the code, which Works fine. However when I try to retrace the stack trace of the obfuscated code, retrace doesn't output an un-obfuscated stacktrace.

I have double check the mapping.txt to sure that i am using the right one.

here is my stack trace

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19398): 
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-35
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19398): java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19398):     at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:954)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19398):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:980)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19398):     at com.excelectronic.b.aa.a(ProGuard:535)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19398):     at com.excelectronic.g.f.a(ProGuard:220)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19398):     at com.excelectronic.game.GameView.a(ProGuard:198)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19398):     at com.excelectronic.game.GameView.onDraw(ProGuard:98)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19398):     at com.excelectronic.game.ac.run(ProGuard:121)
```

and using the command

```
retrace.bat -verbose mapping.txt obfuscated_trace.txt
```

Answer (score 16):

ProGuard's ReTrace tool by default expects the stack traces to be nicely formatted, the way they are printed out by java. This means that it expects line breaks in the proper places and no prefixes like "ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19398)".

Alternatively, you can modify the regular expression that ReTrace uses for parsing the stack traces.

Comment: How can I pass the regular expr pattern? what is the option?

Answer (score 1):

Use [traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) to extract the original Java stack trace before using ReTrace.

Comment: How exactly do you do that?

Comment: Sorry i can't get it to work now. And standalone traceview is deprecated now.

Comment: Here's a simple Regex: `.*(:\u0020)`

Comment: Link is returning 404.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend using Proguard Retrace Unscrambler from Android Studio market place.  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15267-proguard-retrace-unscrambler (you can just copy-paste stack traces instead messing in command line & regex/formatting)

There is the "Normalize" option in which should properly wrap the contents.

Note: "Log file" should have the mapping file

[image]