# Proguard retrace the obfuscated stack trace

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, deobfuscation

In my proguard configuration file, I have :

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile    
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

The obfuscated stack trace of my app crash (in Google Developer Console) is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at ʻ.ˊ(SourceFile:66)
at ˌ.ʻ(SourceFile:120)
```

I followed the [official instruction](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding) about retrace/deobfuscate the obfuscated stack trace by command:

```
./retrace.sh -verbose ~/Download/mapping.txt ~/Download/stacktrace.txt
```

But output is:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1348\cocoasubrtf170
{\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;\f1\fnil\fcharset0 EuphemiaUCAS;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red26\green26\blue26;\red242\green242\blue242;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\deftab720
\pard\pardeftab720\sl360

\f0\fs26 \cf2 \cb3 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0

\outl0\strokewidth0 \strokec2 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
\outl0\strokewidth0 \
\cb3 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\outl0\strokewidth0     at \uc0\u699 .\u714 (SourceFile:66)\cb1 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\outl0\strokewidth0 \
\cb3 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\outl0\strokewidth0     at \uc0\u716 .\u699 (SourceFile:120)\cb1 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\outl0\strokewidth0 \
\cb3 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
```

(I also tried with proguard GUI tool to retrace, but the output is the same as the obfuscated one.)

Where am I wrong? how to de-obfuscate the stack trace (I got from android developer console)?

Comment: its looks like there is double obfuscation on your code, hence you can try to de-obfuscate the file you obtained from de-obfuscation in the first stage

Comment: @Radix There is no de-obfuscation in the first stage, the stacktrace.txt is the obfuscated stack trace I got from Google Android Developer Console directly.

Comment: So you are saying the input file stacktrace.txt and the one you get after you run the retrace.sh (which you can cat >> newstacktrace.txt ) are both same ?

Comment: This might be of help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6726969/2745762

Comment: @Radix, when I use proguardgui.sh to de-obfuscate, the output is the same as the obfuscated stacktrace, when I use retrace.sh to do it, the output is what I have shown above in my question.

Comment: @Leem.fin , do you solve it ? i have same issue .